# Compare if a shorter character vector to a longer in R to determine any match (and which)

Tags: r, vector

I have a set of 800,000 loans, each with a unique loan ID. I want to filter certain criteria so that in a subset I only end up with say, 100 loans. I have the list of those 100 loan IDs and want to verify that the steps were done correctly by comparing my subset to the other subset to see which are present / missing / extra. To simplify my example suppose:

```
 x <- letters 
 y <- letters[2:5]
```

I want to compare x to y so that I will see TRUE for `x[2:5]` and false for all other values of x **even if y is not in the same order as x.** In other words, I want to test if, for each value of x, it is one of the values of y.

This feels simple, the best answer I have found so far is to use a `for()` loop:
    t <- vector(length=length(x))

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  t[i] <- any(x[i]==y)
 }
```

Is there a simpler method?

Comment: `x %in% y` should work.

Comment: `intersect(x,y)` might be useful or `is.element(x, y)`

Comment: @JasonWang this does work on the simplified example, however when I first tried it on my loans data it did not work - I thought it was the function, but I think it might be the data format. Thanks!

Comment: Well, `intersect()` doesn't meet OP's criteria, and from `?is.element`: *"`is.element(x, y)` is identical to `x %in% y`"*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the stringr package is what you are looking for:

```
library(stringr)

str_detect(string = "bcde", pattern = letters)
str_detect(string = "bcde", pattern = "^b")
str_detect(string = "bcde", pattern = "b$")
str_detect(string = "bcde", pattern = "b|f")
str_detect(string = "bbbe", pattern = "b{3}|b{4}")
```

The pattern to look for is by default a regular expression which enables complex patterns as exemplified above.